# SQLite with netbeans not working

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, database-connection

I am trying to add SQLite driver `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar` into my netbeans 7.1.2 project, I have created the database and everything without any problem but when I try to connect to the database with the below code (which I got online) it is not working

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Vinit");

    Statement stat = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists school;");
    stat.executeUpdate("create table school (name, state);");
    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(
                             "insert into school values (?, ?);");

    prep.setString(1, "UTD");
    prep.setString(2, "texas");
    prep.addBatch();
    prep.setString(1, "USC");
    prep.setString(2, "california");
    prep.addBatch();
    prep.setString(1, "MIT");
    prep.setString(2, "massachusetts");
    prep.addBatch();

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    prep.executeBatch();
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);

    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from school;");

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.print("Name of School = " + rs.getString("name") + " ");
        System.out.println("state = " + rs.getString("state"));
    }

    rs.close();
    conn.close();
```

It is giving me a problem with `stat.executeQuery` giving the following error

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   method executeQuery(java.lang.String)
location: variable stat of type java.beans.Statement
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT: Imports

```
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

When I add `import java.sql.Statement;` it gives it an error and says to remove unused import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether `Statement` **interface** is of correct **package** ie.  `java.sql.Statement;`

in your code `import java.beans.Statement;` its **incorrect** change it to `import java.sql.Statement;`

Comment: ya it is in that package alright and I have it imported but for some reason it is not appearing when I use 'stat.'

Comment: @newSpringer will you please post your imports too.

Comment: @newSpringer here import java.beans.Statement; its incorrect change it to java.sql.Statement;

Comment: that did the trick... didnt even notice that import, cheers:)